# I want to disable a button from clicking

Tags: c#, winforms

Bassicly im creating a program that allows the user to enter values and if the values exceed a certain amount then disable a button that was on a different form. But im unsure how to access its buttons control. I thought it would be something like this? Thanx

```
 if(value>120)
 {
  Form3 form3 = new Form3();
  Button.Disable();
  this.close();
 }
```

Comment: Buttons have a `Disabled` property. Set it to true. And you should accept more questions if you want to encourage people to help you.

Comment: @JonathanWood You have that backwards.  Buttons have an `Enabled` property.

Comment: It must be a button on a different form, right? Do you know the form by name? I mean, do you have a `Form3` variable that already points to it?

Comment: @LarsTech: Right you are. That's what I get for mixing technologies and answering questions without testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is to disable a button that *was* on another form - from reading that I assume the form already exists. By creating a new instance:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
```

You're creating a new instance of `Form3` so you'll never disable a button on a form that was already visible.

You'll have to make the current form aware of the *instance* of `Form3` to be able to change anything there. Here are a few ways to make them interact:

- Store these values in a separate object and make your forms react on changes through events for example
- Provide a reference to the instance of `Form3` upon creating or `Show()`ing "this" form
- Keep a reference to each created form in a static class

Also keep in mind having multiple related forms active at the same time may confuse your end-user.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button like this:

```
otherForm.Button.Enabled = false;
```

To be able to disable this button from another context (form), you need to declare it as public. You can do this as follows:

- selecting the button in design view
- in the properties window set *Modifiers* to **Public**

Then you can show the form with the disabled button, like so:

```
var newForm = new Form3();
newForm.Button.Enabled = false;
newForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to an *instance* of Form3. You are creating a new instance of Form3 which is probably not what you wanted. Then your Form3 needs to expose the button you are interested in as a public property so that you can access it from outside of the class. Then you should be able to set the Disabled property to true.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to do something like this.

update

```
 if(value>120)
 {
 Form3 form3 = new Form3();
 form3.Button.Enabled = false;
 this.close();
 }
```

update

Comment: i tried this but it does not grab the button information from the form